# Google Earth Engine - WFS, WMS, and KML feeds

Tags: wms, wfs, kml, google-earth-engine

I'm new to Google Earth Engine, but I am trying to determine if there is a way to produce WFS, WMS, or KML feeds with it. For KML it can't just be the file, but a web service that has a URL.

The end goal is to have a URL that I could have read into another database, but at the moment that database can only take in feeds (no static files). I could also import GeoRSS and GeoJSON feeds, if there is a solution for that within GEE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also starting my studies.
I found something close to what you are looking for in the link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LG4Ijgn3PYQ

Which shows how to configure a WMTS service, for exporting satellite imagery and use in QGIS

Comment: This is a link only answer.  You should explain in the answer why you think your linked content is useful

Comment: If you're adding a video in your answer make sure that at least it's in english. People from other countries may not understand Basilian....